# Class not found using namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I have an class called Alumno.class.php, locate in Root\Classes\Abm\Alumno.class.php.
So this class header is:

```
/**
 * Gestiona las operaciones ABM del tipo de usuario alumno.
 * La clase no realiza validaciones, eso será labor del controlador.
 * @package AdminManantiales
 * @subpackage Abm
 * @author Ramiro Martínez D'Elía
 */

namespace AdminManantiales\Classes\Abm;

class Alumno extends Usuario{ // Implement }
```

Now, I need to use the class in a php script, and try with this:

```
use \AdminManantiales\Classes\Abm\Alumno as AbmAlumno;
[...]
// Proceso el alta.
$alumno = new AbmAlumno();
$alumno->alta($_POST);
$nombreCompleto = $alumno->toStr();
```

But it fails in the `$alumno = new AbmAlumno();` line. With the next message:

> Class 'AdminManantiales\Classes\Abm\Alumno' not found

How do I include correctly the class using the "use" keyword ?.

Comment: are you using composer ?

Comment: Do you have an autoloader set up or are including the file containing the class when you are instantiating it?

Comment: just a note: We have the same last name! :P

Comment: `use` does not import / include anything. You still have to require the file if you aren't using an autoloader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `use` keyword doesn't *actually* do anything. You'll have to either include the [PHP](http://php.net/) script manually, using `include \AdminManantiales\Classes\Abm\Alumno.php` (or whatever the filepath is) or use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php) like this,

```
function autoload($classId)
{
    $classIdParts       = explode("\\", $classId);
    $classIdLength      = count($classIdParts);
    $className          = strtolower($classIdParts[$classIdLength - 1]);
    $namespace          = strtolower($classIdParts[0]);

    for ($i = 1; $i < $classIdLength - 1; $i++) {
        $namespace .= '/' . $classIdParts[$i];
    }

    if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)) 
        . '/' . $namespace 
        . '/' . $className 
        . '.class.php') {
        include $namespace . '/' . $className . '.class.php';
    }
}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

You can then store this script and include it whichever script you use the `use` keyword.

Comment: `The use keyword doesn't actually do anything`, so what actually it does? why is it exist?

Comment: As I understand it, Namespaces exist just to define scoping rules for a file or group of files. These files can contain functions, classes, etc. They don't actually do anything. Defining a namespace won't actually find that file and include it, that you have to do yourself. What it does is define a scope for the file thats already been include it.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use autoloading with composer (`App` and `src/` would be different for you though):

```
{
    "require": {

    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "App": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

You might also have to run `composer.phar dumpautoload` in the console.